# How to include PHP file with JavaScript and pass parameters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, web

I need to run a PHP function in a page, after the user clicks on something, in this case, a link.

First I was using onclick to run a javascript AJAX to request a PHP file with the function in it. The thing is, I need to pass a parameter to the function, and I can't seem to be able to do it with AJAX.

If it was a PHP include, it would behave like it 'appended' the other file to the current file, so this way, the included file could reference variables in the current file. Apparently, AJAX is just taking the file I need, running it's code, and displaying the results. So yeah, doesn't work for me.

So basically. I need an exact replica of PHP's 'include', on JavaScript.
OR any other workaround.

My current code:

```
<br> <div id="seeMore"> </div> <br>

<ul> <li style="float: left"> <a href="#" onclick="loadMore();">Ver Mais</a> </li> </ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
function loadMore()
{ $("#seeMore").load("feedP.php"); }
</script>
```

This is the part of the code in the main page that im needing help with, you can see it's loading a page called feedP.php, here's it's code:

```
<?php

echo 'test';
require_once('functions.php'); loadFeeds($urls, 5);

?>
```

As you can see, I have to run a function called loadFeeds, and it requires a parameter, $urls. Witch is created back on the main page.

EDIT:

I CAN'T reload the page, or redirect the user, that's why i'm trying to 'append' the file here.

Comment: Use a `POST` / `GET` request and pass the parameters through the `data` property.

Comment: No, you'd simply pass the parameters and that would be done dynamically, please see my answer below.

Comment: If you can't reload the page then you'd be best off loading an AJAX request.  The answer provided below does sufficiently answer the question you asked.  If you're confused about the answer provided, a bit more explanation of where you are stuck will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the second parameter of the `load` function which takes parameters that can be posted to the file in question:

```
$("#seeMore").load("feedP.php", {
    url: 'url'
});
```

Then, in your PHP you can make use of `$_POST` to access the posted data.

> data
>
> Type: PlainObject or String
>
> A plain object or string that is sent to the server with the request.

**Reading Material**

[`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: @RaviMattar that is an object where the unquoted `url` is the key which you'd use to access the quoted value in PHP. In the quotes, you'd put your URL.

Comment: Any way to prevent the page from scrolling up?

Comment: Yes, remove the # from your href, replace it with `javascript:void(0)`.

Comment: For some reason, this is only working the first time the user clicks to load more. Why woud that be?

Comment: @RaviMattar ensure you have more data to actually get, secondly, check the response from the request.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the parameters through load function. I have altered your script code as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadMore() { 
   $("#seeMore").load("feedP.php", {urls: "<?php echo $url; ?>"}); 
}
</script>
```

In the above code $url is the php variable which you assign the url you need to pass to feedp.php